# How to automatically install all required packages?

Tags: r, rstudio

Right now, I resolve dependencies with the following method:

1. Source the file.
2. If it complains about needing package X, install package X.
3. Go to 1.

If there is a large number of required packages this can get tedious. Is there a single command that can determine every required package and then automatically install them all?

I have RStudio 0.98.1056 and R 3.3.1.

Comment: Build a package. Then when you install it all dependencies can be installed.

Comment: https://github.com/brianhigh/imp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use package [pacman](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pacman/vignettes/Introduction_to_pacman.html).The `p_load` function looks if the listed packages are installed , installs them if they are missing and loads them too.Here is my sample implementation for a r-shiny app.

`if(!require('pacman'))install.packages('pacman')
pacman::p_load(shiny,shinyjs,httr,jsonlite,tidyverse)`

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to find all the necessary packages in an R script.

```
# list packages in an R file 
  filename <- "C:/Data/Documents/R/myFile.R"
  tmp <- getParseData(parse(filename, keep.source=TRUE))
  crit <- quote(token == "SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL")
  tmp <- dplyr::filter(tmp, .dots = crit)
  tmp <- unique(sort(tmp$text))
  src <- paste(as.vector(sapply(tmp, find)))
  outlist <- tapply(tmp,factor(src),c)
  outlist
```

You can then look at the output and install the ones that you do not already have.  Not automatic, but it gets you most of the way there!

(note - I did not originally write this code... found it somewhere)

Edit: @Rich Scriven - you are correct!  I purposefully put a new function in a script and it was listed under Character(0).  You would have to then find the package using ?? perhaps to then install it.

Edit 2: I worked on the problem and came up with this to add to the above code.  It will find packages that are unattached and if they are in the library, attach them.  If not, install them.

```
 library(sos)
  toInstall <- outlist$`character(0)`
  for(i in 1:length(toInstall)){
    newPackage<-findFn(toInstall[i])[1,4]
    if (!require(newPackage,character.only = TRUE)) {
      install.packages(newPackage)
      library(newPackage,character.only = TRUE)
    }
    print(newPackage)
  }
```

Comment: How would this work if the packages aren't installed? `find` returns `character(0)` if unfound, right?  Some explanation would be nice here.